# DPD Webservices - How to generate Multi-Page Labels for Split Shipments

Tags: php, soap, shipping-method

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using the **[blobswop/dpd-php-api](https://github.com/blobswop/dpd-php-api)** for integrating with the DPD Webservice API. My objective is to generate shipping labels and tracking numbers for parcel shipments. Creating a single label per shipment is already working without any issues. Here's an example of how I'm currently generating single-page labels:

**Service to generate Label and Tracking**

```
public function getLabel(string $serviceMode, int $orderId, int $shippingServiceId): StoreOrdersResponseType
    {
        if (Configure::read('override.service_mode')) {
            Api::dev();
        } else {
            switch ($serviceMode) {
                case 'live':
                    Api::prod();
                    break;
                case 'sandbox':
                    Api::dev();
                    break;
            }
        }

        $shippingService = $this->shippingServicesTable->get($shippingServiceId);
        $order = $this->ordersTable->get($orderId);
        $recipientNames = $this->prepareDpdRecipientNames($order);

        $authentication =
            (new Authentication())
                ->setDelisId($shippingService->username)
                ->setAuthToken($shippingService->auth_token)
                ->setMessageLanguage('de_DE');

        $storeOrders =
            (new StoreOrders())
                ->setPrintOptions(
                    (new PrintOptions())
                        ->addPrintOption(
                            (new PrintOption())
                                ->setPaperFormatA6()
                                ->setOutputFormat(OutputFormatType::pdf())
                        )
                        ->setSplitByParcel(true)
                )
                ->addOrder(
                    (new ShipmentServiceData())
                        ->setGeneralShipmentData(
                            (new GeneralShipmentData())
                                ->setProduct($shippingService->shipping_service_code)
                                ->setSendingDepot($shippingService->depot)
                                ->setMpsWeight($shippingService->weight)
                                ->setSender(
                                    (new AddressWithType())
                                        ->setAddressTypeCommercial()
                                        ->setName1($shippingService->company)
                                        ->setName2($shippingService->name)
                                        ->setStreet($shippingService->street)
                                        ->setHouseNo($shippingService->house_no)
                                        ->setCountry($shippingService->country_code)
                                        ->setZipCode($shippingService->postcode)
                                        ->setCity($shippingService->city)
                                )
                                ->setRecipient(
                                    (new AddressWithType())
                                        ->setAddressType((isset($order->company) ? 'COM' : 'PRV'))
                                        ->setName1($recipientNames['name1'])
                                        ->setName2($recipientNames['name2'])
                                        ->setStreet($order->street)
                                        ->setHouseNo($order->house_no)
                                        ->setCountry($order->country_code)
                                        ->setZipCode($order->postcode)
                                        ->setCity($order->city)
                                )
                                ->setIdentificationNumber('Your-Shipment-Id')
                        )
                        ->addParcel(
                            (new Parcel())
                                ->setWeight($shippingService->weight)
                                ->setCustomerReferenceNumber1($order->customer_reference_number1)
                                ->setCustomerReferenceNumber2($order->customer_reference_number2 ?? ' ')
                                ->setAddServiceParcelBox()
                        )
                        ->setProductAndServiceData(
                            (new ProductAndServiceData())
                                ->setOrderTypeConsignment()
                                ->setFood(false)
                        )
                );

        $response = Api::me()->storeOrders($authentication, $storeOrders);

        if ($response instanceof AuthenticationFault) {
            Log::error('LabelService() Authentication Fault: ' . print_r($response, true), ['scope' => 'dpd']);
        } elseif ($response instanceof StoreOrdersResponseType) {
            $currentYear = date('Y');
            $currentMonth = date('m');
            $baseDir = WWW_ROOT . 'shipping-labels' . DS . $currentYear . DS . $currentMonth;

            if (!file_exists($baseDir)) {
                mkdir($baseDir, 0755, true);
            }

            $shipmentResponse = $response->getShipmentResponses()[0];
            if (
                $shipmentResponse instanceof ShipmentResponse
                && $shipmentResponse->getParcelInformation() instanceof ParcelInformationType
                && $shipmentResponse->getParcelInformation()->getParcelLabelNumber()
                && $shipmentResponse->getParcelInformation()->getOutput() instanceof OutputType
                && $shipmentResponse->getParcelInformation()->getOutput()->getContent()
            ) {
                $format = $shipmentResponse->getParcelInformation()->getOutput()->getFormat();
                $labelNumber = $shipmentResponse->getParcelInformation()->getParcelLabelNumber();
                $content = $shipmentResponse->getParcelInformation()->getOutput()->getContent();

                if ($format == OutputFormatType::TYPE_PDF) {
                    $suffix = ($serviceMode === 'live' ? '' : '_sandbox');
                    $filePath = $baseDir . DS . $labelNumber . $suffix . '.pdf';
                    file_put_contents($filePath, $content);
                }
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
```

However, I've encountered a challenge: How can I create a label that consists of multiple pages when a shipment needs to be divided across multiple packages? Each package gets its own tracking number, but all the packages belong to a single shipment and should be grouped under one common Shipment ID.

I noticed that through the DPD Portal, it's possible to generate multi-page labels. For example, you can see this in action here: [DPD Multi-Page Label Example](https://tracking.dpd.de/status/de_DE/shipment/B2C0114681768070020231214). Is there a way to replicate this functionality using the DPD Webservices API?

Does anyone have experience with this specific requirement or any suggestions on how I can implement this? Any advice or example code would be immensely helpful.